# Generate Rate widget for specific user based on UID

Tags: users, rating

Basically, I'm going to be displaying a list of users who have voted on a node, but then show in a modal what their rating was. Now I can use the voting api to get what they voted, but I can't generate a display only widget for what they voted based on the user ID.

Any ideas? This is the function from the Rate module.

```
/**
 * Generate a widget.
 *
 * @param int $widget_id Widget id
 * @param string $content_type "node" or "comment"
 * @param int $content_id Node id (nid) or comment id (cid)
 * @param bool $teaser
 * @param bool $include_div
 * @return array
 */
function rate_generate_widget($widget_id, $content_type, $content_id, $mode = RATE_FULL, $include_div = TRUE, $just_voted = FALSE, $displayed = NULL) {}
```

Comment: i think you should try out views module for it

Comment: @harshal I've tried, but it just doesn't work out the same.

Comment: pls let me know how have u used views for this

Comment: So I used Views to create a list of users who have voted on a node, grouped by what their rating was, and [that works fine](http://i.imgur.com/iyObEBo.png). The issue is showing all the other ratings given on the same node by individual users in like a popup or hover that looks [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/Vq94o4c.png)

Answer (score 0):

What i understand that you want to display that Current logged in user Content ratings. for that you can use the **(Votes) Votes: Current user (True)** for filter 
[image]
and if you want to display all the voted content User-wise than you can Make a relation with **(Votes) Votes: User** and remove the **(Votes) Votes: Current user (True)** as the following image.
[image]

Comment: Not quite. I want to show the individual ratings from the current user's friends who have voted.

Comment: So how do you make the relation with the friends.

Comment: So with this [View](http://i.imgur.com/bhhsESH.png), it shows a list of the current user's friends who voted on the current node using contextual filters. Now I can add their individual ratings for that node using Views Field View, but it's not very clean and the markup is terrible, so I'm trying to find a much cleaner process.